# Iterative CORDIC algorithm dynamic shift optimization

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, cordic

I've implemented the CORDIC algorithm on an FPGA using an iterative approach. The component is loaded with a set of values to calculate and then iterates as many CORDIC steps as necessary for the required precision. In contrast to a fully pipelined version which accepts new inputs on every clock cycle the iterative version does require far less registers and logic, but the shift operation of the main CORDIC step does turn into a dynamic shift with the shift distance depending on the current iteration:

\$x_{i+1} = x_i \mp 2^{-i} y_i \\
y_{i+1} = y_i \pm 2^{-i} x_i\$

This dynamic shift and add currently does limit my maximum frequency (only ~80MHz instead of the targeted 100MHz on an Altera MAX 10 for 32 bit precision).  I’ve thought about ways to turn this shift into one with a constant distance but I think that is not possible. I’ve also searched for articles on optimized CORDIC algorithms, but I haven’t really found anything suitable (all the interesting sounding ones seem to be not publicly accessible).

Is there any other trick to optimize the latency of this algorithm? Splitting the shift and addition into two clock cycles and therefore doubling the number of required clock cycles is not acceptable. Increasing the number of required logic is acceptable as long as it’s still smaller than the fully pipelined version.

Comment: How exactly are you implementing the shift operation? A barrel shifter?

Comment: Whatever the synthesis tool turns `shift_right` into. Looking at the implementation it seems to be a barrel shifter or something similar.

Comment: Have you analyzed the timing results and are confident that it's the barrel shifter causing the frequency to diminish? For example, if there's a very long path between the answer and whatever register is receiving that answer, that could be factoring into your max frequency. A quick check for that would be to add a register chain to the input "loading" path and add registers between the answer and the dest reg. If it truly is the shifter, maybe you could take advantage of some of the hard dsp blocks of the MAX 10 to perform shifting via multiply. You can precompute 2^-i. May not be any better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the barrel shifter together with the addition. The addition also takes quite a long time, but a little less than the shift. I've already tried replacing the shift with a multiplier, but that was even slower. Currently I'm trying to optimize the addition using carry-free addition.

Comment: The solution with least resource usage does serial CORDIC rounds and (LSB first) bit-serial processing using a 1-bit stream adder with one register for carry. Variable shifts translate into variable delays. You can trick a MK9-block in true dual port mode into doing these delays with proper adressing scheme. For 23 bits precision, latency will be 506 cycles (22 rounds * 23 bits). Please indicate if bit-serial processing is an option.